# How to retrieve all local variables of another module?

Tags: python

I am receiving a module as a parameter and I would like to retrieve all of it's local variables (nothing that relates to **XXX** or a function or a class).
How can that be done?

I have tried:

```
def _get_settings(self, module):
        return [setting for setting in dir(module) if not inspect.ismodule(setting) and not inspect.isbuiltin(setting) and not inspect.isfunction(setting) and not setting.__NAME__.startswith('__')]
```

but it raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omer/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_1.6.5.2011012519/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1133, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/home/omer/Aptana Studio 3/plugins/org.python.pydev.debug_1.6.5.2011012519/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 918, in run
    execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "/root/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/website/website/manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    import settings
  File "/root/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/website/website/settings.py", line 7, in <module>
    settings_loader = Loader(localsettings)
  File "/root/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/website/website/envconf/loader.py", line 6, in __init__
    self.load(environment)
  File "/root/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/website/website/envconf/loader.py", line 9, in load
    for setting in self._get_settings(module):
  File "/root/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/website/website/envconf/loader.py", line 16, in _get_settings
    return [setting for setting in dir(module) if not inspect.ismodule(setting) and not inspect.isbuiltin(setting) and not inspect.isfunction(setting) and not setting.__NAME__.startswith('__')]
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__NAME__'
```

Comment: You probably meant `__name__`, not `__NAME__`. Python is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access all of the local variables with `dir()`. This returns a list of strings, where each string is the name of the attribute. This returns all of the variables as well as the methods.  If you are looking specifically for just the instance variables, these can be accessed through `__dict__` for example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, a, b, c):
>>>
>>> f = Foo(1,2,3)
>>> f.__dict__
{'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
>>> dir(f)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 2):

`dir()` returns a list of strings. Use `setting.startswith()` directly.