# Get locals from calling namespace in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I want to retrieve the local variables from Python from a called function. Is there any way to do this? I realize this isn't right for most programming, but I am basically building a debugger. For example:

```
def show_locals():
  # put something in here that shows local_1.

local_1 = 123
show_locals()  # I want this to show local_1.
```

What do I put in the body of `show_locals`? If I have to modify the calling statement, what is the minimal modification I can make?

**Note:** this must work when `show_locals` is in a different module to its caller.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you're writing a debugger, you'll want to make heavy use of the [`inspect`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module:

```
def show_callers_locals():
    """Print the local variables in the caller's frame."""
    import inspect
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    try:
        print(frame.f_back.f_locals)
    finally:
        del frame
```

Comment: Yay! I found your solution after running into significant performance issues with an alternative solution: `caller = inspect.stack()[1][0]; myvars = caller.f_locals`. Your way is MUCH faster.

Comment: Why is deleting the `frame` in the `finally` block necessary? Is keeping the frame object in memory somehow expensive? This is a minor point, of course, but it left me confused. Also, thank you, this is very helpful!

Comment: The [`inspect` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) explains the `del frame`.

Comment: @user21952-is-a-great-name and Gareth, it seems to me the `del frame` (and thus the try block) is actually a no-op, since the `frame` variable is about to go out of scope anyway.  No?

Comment: @DonHatch: See my comment of 2016-11-02.

Comment: Yes, i see your comment referring to the example in the inspect documentation, and I see that that example has `del frame`, but that does not address my question.

Comment: @DonHatch: Did you read the note in the documentation I linked to? (The whole note, not just the example.)

Comment: Yes.  If I understand it correctly, it's suggesting that you can help the garbage collector by explicitly clearing the variable so that it the garbage collector doesn't need to rely on cycle detection.   Some ways of doing that are:  `del frame`, or `frame = None`, or just let the variable go out of scope.  In your case the variable is about to go out of scope anyway, so there's no point in doing either of those other things.

Comment: Ah wait, I get it.   "go out of scope" means, literally, that the stack frame that owns the local variable is about to be released.  But, 'frame' points to exactly that stack frame.  That's the cycle they are talking about.  Ok, I concede the `del frame` is useful.   OTOH I'm not sure the variable is necessary at all.   I think the function body could be  `print(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals)`

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps it is worth pointing out that the technique from the accepted answer that reads from the caller's stack frame:

```
import inspect
def read_from_caller(varname):
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    try:
        v = frame.f_locals[varname]
        return v
    finally:
        del frame
```

can also write into the caller's namespace:

```
import inspect
def write_in_caller(varname, v):
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    try:
        frame.f_locals[varname] = v
    finally:
        del frame
```

If you put that in a module called "access_caller", then

```
import access_caller
access_caller.write_in_caller('y', x)
```

is an elaborate way of writing

```
y = x
```

(I am writing this as a fresh answer because I don't have enough reputation points to write a comment.)

Comment: Hi @daniel, it seems it does not work in python3.8 at least. The __setitem__ call on f_locals has no effect

Comment: Hi @grégoire-roussel, Can you share a code example? For me, writing "x = 45", then "write_in_caller('y', x)", then "print(y)" reports 45 as expected. I am using python 3.8.5 in linux.

Answer (score 0):

You use the python builtin, dir() or vars():

vars(object)

For examples using dir(), see: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748448/how-to-retrieve-all-local-variables-of-another-module)

Examples using vars:

```
>>> class X:
...     a=1
...     def __init__(self):
...         b=2
... 
>>> 
>>> vars(X)
{'a': 1, '__module__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0x100488848>}
>>> 
>>> vars(X())
{}
```

A potentially problematic fact: New style classes not return the same result

```
>>> class X(object):
...     a=1
...     def __init__(self):
...         b=2
... 
>>> 
>>> vars(X)
<dictproxy object at 0x1004a1910>
>>> vars(X())
{}
```

Also: for an instantiated class (new and old style), if you add a variable after instantiating, vars will return the object's **dict** like this:

```
>>> x = X() 
>>> x.c = 1
>>> vars(x)
{'c': 1}
>>>
```

See:  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars

Comment: This doesn't answer the question,  the OP wants the oppersite where inside of func_1, if you call func_2 you can see all the locals from func_1.