# Python locals() for containing scope

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, environment, locals

TL;DR: I want a locals() that looks in a containing scope.

Hi, all.

I'm teaching a course on Python programming to some chemist friends, and I want to be sure I really understand scope.

Consider:

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        print(locals())
        print(globals())
    b()
```

Locals prints an empty environment, and globals prints the usual globals. How do I get access to the environment where x is stored? Clearly the interpreter knows about it because I can refer to it.

Related: When does scoping happen? The following nameErrors on a = x+2 only if x=3 is included:

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        a = x+2
        x = 3
    b()
```

If you comment out x=3, the code works. Does this mean that python makes a lexical-scope pass over the code before it interprets it?

Comment: do you need a list? because you could just do print x after print globals. EDIT: forget to say if you access x with print x then is also locals() filled with x:1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get locals from calling namespace in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618795/get-locals-from-calling-namespace-in-python)

Answer (score 7):

What is happening in your code is that when python see's the `x=3` line in your `b()` method, it is recreating `x` with a scope within the `b` function instead of using the `x` with it's scope in the `a` function.

because your code then goes:

```
    a = x+2
    x = 3
```

it is saying that you need to define the inner scoped `x` before referencing it.

however, when you do not have the assigning of `x` within the `b` function python does not attempt to make a lower scoped `x` and will not throw any errors.

The following code will illustrate this:

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        x = 3
        print (x)

    def c():
        print (x)

    b()
    c()
    print (x)

a()
```

However if you were to declare `x` as `global` you could use it within a function, like so:

```
def a():
    global x
    x = 1

    def d():
        global x
        x += 2

    print (x)
    d()
    print (x)

a()
```

Python 3 has also added a `nonlocal` keyword that will let you access a variable from an enclosing scope, usage is like:

```
def a():
    x = 1

    def d():
        nonlocal x
        x += 2

    print (x)
    d()
    print (x)

a()
```

Will print the same results as the `global` example.

---

In case I miss-read the question:

As per the answer to [Get locals from calling namespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6618795/get-locals-from-calling-namespace-in-python):

you can use:

```
import inspect

def a():
    x = 1

    def d():
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        try:
            print (frame.f_back.f_locals)
        finally:
            del frame
    d()

a()
```

to get the local scope of the functions caller.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Python 3 has added a `nonlocal` keyword that you can use in the inner function to be able to rebind an existing name from an enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1):

The statement `print(locals())` refers to nearest enclosing scope, that is the `def b():` function. When calling `b()`, you will print the locals to this b function, and definition of x is outside the scope.

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        print(locals())
        print(globals())
    b()
    print(locals())
```

would print x as a local variable.

For your second question:

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        #a = x+2
        x = 3
    b()

>>> a()
```

gives no error.

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        a = x+2
        #x = 3
    b()

>>> a()
```

gives no error.

And

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        a = x+2
        x = 3
    b()

>>> a()
```

gives following error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment`

IMO (please check), in this third case, first statement in the body of `b()` looks for value of x *in the most enclosing scope*. And in this scope, x is assigned on the next line. If you only have statement `a = x+2`, x is not found in most enclosing scope, and is found in the 'next' enclosing scope, with `x = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`python3 -c "help(locals)"` says this about the `locals` function:

```
locals()
    Return a dictionary containing the current scope's local variables.
```

That means that calling `locals()` in `b()` will only show you which variables are local to `b()`.  That doesn't mean that `b()` can't see variables outside its scope -- but rather, `locals()` only returns information for variables local to `b()`.

What you probably want is to make `b()` show information on the variables of the calling function.  To do that, take this code (which show's `b()`'s local variables):

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        print(locals())
    b()
```

and replace it with this one (which uses the `inspect` module to get you the local information of the calling frame):

```
def a():    
    x = 1
    def b():
        import inspect
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals)
    b()
```

---

As for your other issue:

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        a = x+2
        x = 3
    b()
```

The error you get is because Python 3 allows you to set/assign global variables and variables local to outside scopes provided you declare them with the `global` and `nonlocal` keywords.  (I won't explain them here; I'll just say that you won't have any problem looking them up yourself.)

If you remove the `x = 3` line (keeping the `a = x+2` line), your code will run because `x`'s value is being used, but not set.  If instead you remove the `a = x+2` line (keeping the `x = 3` line), your code will run because it will create a new `x` inside `b()`'s scope.

If you keep both lines, Python doesn't know whether `x` is supposed to refer to an `x` outside the current scope (as `a = x+2` seems to suggest) or if it's supposed to refer to an `x` local to `b()`'s scope (as `x = 3` suggests).

If you want `x` to be local to `b()`, then you shouldn't have that `a = x+2` line there, at least not before `x` is set with `x = 3`.  But if you want `x` to be `a()`'s `x`, then you should declare `x` as `nonlocal` to `b()`, like this:

```
def a():
    x = 1
    def b():
        nonlocal x  # use a()'s x
        a = x+2
        x = 3
    b()
```

If you're confused, remember that Python will let you *use* global variables and variables created outside of your current scope, but only if you don't *assign* to them.  (It's often acceptable to read global variables, but it's frowned upon to set them.)

If you want to set a global variable or a non-local variable, you will have to declare those variables with `global` (for global variables) or `nonlocal` (for non-local variables), as shown in the above code.

I hope this helps.