# Access variable declared in a function from another function

Tags: python

How to access a variable `x` that is local for a function `main()` from another function `sub()` that is called inside `main()`?

The MEW below throws an error `NameError: global name 'x' is not defined` when the script is run.

If I add `global x, l` in `main()` there are no errors anymore, but I do not want to make these variables global as such.

MWE:

```
def sub():
    print "x from main: {}".format(x)
    print "l from main: {}".format(l)


def main():
    x = 5
    l = [1,2,3,4,5]
    print "z from top: {}".format(z)
    sub()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = 'SOME'
    main()
```

**Edit1** I am editing an existing code and prefer not to change arity of functions

Comment: Pass them as arguments to the function.

Answer (score 3):

Passing the parameters as arguments gets what you want done.

```
def sub(x, l):
    print "x from main: {}".format(x)
    print "l from main: {}".format(l)


def main(z):
    x = 5
    l = [1,2,3,4,5]
    print "z from top: {}".format(z)
    sub(x, l)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = 'SOME'
    main(z)
```

This prints:

```
z from top: SOME
x from main: 5
l from main: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you don't want to use this approach, I guess you could follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6618825/225020) answer's approach, although seems convoluted for a case like this.

```
import inspect

z = 'SOME'

def sub():
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    locales = None
    try: locales = frame.f_back.f_locals
    finally: del frame
    if locales:
        for k, v in locales.items():
            print("{} from main: {}".format(k, v))


def main():
    x = 5
    l = [1,2,3,4,5]
    print("z from top: {}".format(z))
    sub()

main(z)
```

Maybe this would be cleaner if you could turn this into a context manager.

You could also use `*args` and `*kwargs`

```
def function(*args, **kwargs):
    if args:
        for a in args:
            print "value: {} was passed in args".format(a)
    if kwargs:
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            print "key {} was passed with value: {} in kwargs".format(k, v)


def caller():
    x = 5
    l = [1,2,3,4,5]
    function(x, l = l)

caller()
#value: 5 was passed in args
#key l was passed with value: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] in kwargs
```

From here you can assign values to `locals`

*within `function`*

```
locals['x'] = args[0]
locals['l'] = kwargs[l]
```

**OR** use `dict.get` this way you can set defaults:

```
l = kwargs.get('l', None)
```

Comment: I am editing already existing code and I prefer not to change arity of functions.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Added another option

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do what you'd like, also requires the least amount of changes. Just change the way you're declaring the variables; by adding the function name before the variable name, you're able to access the variable from anywhere in your code.

```
def sub():
    print "x from main: {}".format(main.x)
    print "l from main: {}".format(main.l)

def main():
    main.x = 5
    main.l = [1,2,3,4,5]
    print "z from top: {}".format(z)
    sub()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = 'SOME'
    main()
```

This will print:

```
z from top: SOME
x from main: 5
l from main: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```